# bad performance while clicking row

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I have html table which i bind to using knockout observable array `TableDataList` like below

```
<div  style="overflow: hidden;margin-top: 30px;margin-left: 10px;float:left;" >
    <table style="width: 100%" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="padding: 0px">Id </th>
                <th style="padding: 0px">Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <div style="overflow: auto;height: 490px;">
        <table id ="Table1" style="width: 100%;" >
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: TableDataList">
                <tr  data-bind= "click: $root.giveDetails">
                    <td style="padding: 0px;text-align: left" data-bind="text: Id"></td>
                    <td style="padding: 0px;" data-bind="text: Name "></td>
                </tr>   
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently i am loading about 5000 rows in table but it takes about 5 seconds to click the row. I have knockout binding on click event `data-bind= "click: $root.giveDetails"` of row which calls some service and loads data

I can see that when i click on row it loads data first and then marks the row. I highlight row with blue color when it is clicked. When the data is less in table then there is no problem but performance degrades when there is about 5000 records. Can someone point me to tips on how to improve this?

**Update 1**

This is click event of my tr

```
 this.giveDetails= function (item) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../Service/Table/TableData",
        type: "PUT",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        processData: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(item.Id()),
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            alert(errorThrown);
        },
        success: function (allData) {
            var mappedData= $.map(allData, function (item) {

                return new TableData(item);
            });
            self.AnotherTableDataList(mappedData);
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Can you post the click handler `giveDetails`?

Comment: It sounds like you've got two tables. Which one has 5000 records, the first one (being clicked) or the second (loaded when the first one is clicked)?

Comment: @xdumaine The first one being clicked. Also edited my question. Instead of self.TableDataList(mappedData), i used self.AnotherTableDataList(mappedData)

Comment: I'm confused. Your explanation says the click handler is `ShowSingleSysTableDetail` but the code has the click handler is `giveDetails` - which doesn't make sense. In `giveDetails` you're reloading the entire original table.

Comment: @xdumaine sorry it was copy paste error. Now rectified

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58780/discussion-between-happy-and-xdumaine).

Comment: @xdumaine i am not loading same table on click event. Its another data which i am loading. It was some copy paste error on my part. Please help me.

Comment: @Happy You should spend some time reviewing your code and creating a minimal example that has the same performance issues. We generally cannot debug something that we cannot see.

Comment: @PegLeg3941 i dont know how to make dummy data

Comment: @Happy It isn't so much about dummy data as letting us see what your code is doing. I see code above but have no idea how it ties in with your table.

Comment: @PegLeg3941 My code is tied to knockout observable array which is loaded from service.

Comment: Please help me as i am still struggling with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may be in large amount of event handlers (one per each of 5000 rows). So the idea is to bind click event to table body and then on in your `giveDetails` function you need to calculate what exact row was clicked. Like this:

```
...
<table id ="Table1" style="width: 100%;" >
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: TableDataList, click: $root.giveDetails">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 0px;text-align: left" data-bind="text: Id"></td>
            <td style="padding: 0px;" data-bind="text: Name "></td>
        </tr>   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

...
And later in your model:

```
giveDetails: function(data, e) {
    alert($(e.target).parents('tr').find('td:first').text());
}
```

Now this is not really a good practise to mix knockout viewmodels with jQuery code, but this is the starting idea, maybe there's a better solution. Here is [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IEBvs) with 5000 rows. Feel free to update this code, let's solve this problem together :)

#### UPDATE:

I refactored my code a little to get `item` inside click handler:

```
giveDetails: function(data, e) {
  if ($(e.target).prop("tagName") != 'TD')
      return;
  var id = $(e.target).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
  var item = ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.TableDataList(), function(arrayItem) {
      return arrayItem.Id == id;
  });
  alert(item.Id + ', ' + item.Name);
}
```

Demo link is the same.

Comment: In your example it takes so long time to show alert when i click on row. Why is it so?

Comment: Hmm, it fires instantly on my machine. What browser do you use (I've tried in IE11, latest Chrome and FF).

Comment: But do you have other solution because even i dont like mixing jquery code and knockout. I will try your solution now and reply in 10 minutes

Comment: What if i want to find second or third and so on td

Comment: See my updated code - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IEBvs. You just use indexer. I think there is no way to avoid some DOM manipulation in this approach, unfortunately. Did this help to speed up your solution at least?

Comment: I get undefined when i click on row

Comment: Oops, firefox didn't understand that. Try again, I changed it a little bit. The main question is - does it help at all or performance is the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58811/discussion-between-happy-and-ilya-luzyanin).

Comment: Performance is bit improved but problem is that when i click on row i call WCF service which loads data and that data is bonded to another table. If i comment that code to not call wcf service on row click then its very fast even with my approach. With your approach you are not calling any service to load data. Although the data returned from WCF service when i click row is very very small. So its very hard to understand for me as to why it behaves like this. Can you call some data when you click on row?

Comment: I will be happy if you can come in discussion. I have sent you few more images

Comment: it takes 4 seconds to display alert and then immediately it marks the row.. so it is something to do with ajax call? But then its strange because when there are less number of rows in grid then it takes less time . In both cases i call same ajax request and it returns me almost same amount of data

Comment: i dont believe its server problem. This issue is with all part of my application. So dont know if i should unaccept answer. I dont want to hurt you at all and dont think any negatively about me.

Comment: Do as you feel right. My answer is still correct in the matter of improving performance.

Comment: I have upvoted you but will wait more for someone who can answer or i can accept it.

Comment: i put up another question. If possible answer it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197919/something-wrong-with-performace