# something wrong with performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf, knockout.js

I am using jquery,knockout and WCF. I am loading data coming from WCF via Ajax request and push data into observable array. This observable array is binded to html table

```
<div  style="overflow: hidden;" >
<table style="width: 100%" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id </th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<div style="overflow: auto;height: 320px;">
    <table id ="Table1" style="width: 100%;" >
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: ListOfArray">
            <tr  data-bind= "click: showData">
                <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
                <td  data-bind="text: Name "></td>
            </tr>   
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

When i click on row then it takes 4-5 seconds to select it. I put profiler when i click on row. This is what it shows

[image]

Can someone point me where is it slowing down and why?

Comment: Any chance for a larger image?  Tell us more about the WCF bit

Comment: @MickyDuncan how do i show larger image? WCF is returning me data when i call it

Comment: @MickyDuncan can you zoom your page so its more easy to read from image?

Comment: Oh the zoom worked.  So how many items is the WCF service returning that are being bound into your table?

Comment: @MickyDuncan WCF returns data only once

Comment: No, how many **rows** are in your table?

Comment: @MickyDuncan i have about 5000 rows in table. The performace is good if just have 200 rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58949/discussion-between-happy-and-micky-duncan).

Comment: You should not be showing 5000 items.

Comment: @MickyDuncan Customer needs it so i am helpless

Answer (score 0):

From your comments you have said your HTML table is displaying *"5000 rows"* when performance is **poor** but *"performace is **good** if just have 200 rows".*

Generally an app should **not** attempt to display a large number of items (in this case 5000) due to memory limitations and the impact on performance as you have discovered.

The most common practice is to just do paging and show say 20 items at a time complete with **Previous**; **Next** and *page numbers*.

An alternative approach if you don't want paging is to redesign your table to be a *virtual table* where you essentially there is no limit on the number of items that could be represented (virtual views only load into memory **what can be seen** and **not** what is *off-screen*).  Thank the endless scrolling on *Facebook*.

Comment: My problem is not about rendering 5000 rows. Is about taking more time to click row

Comment: @happy Your problem I fear is _memory_.  Even if it were not, I certainly would not wish to visit a web site that fetches 5000 items!